# EAS Build Permission Denied Error When Running eas-build-pre-install Script on

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm encountering a "Permission denied" error when EAS Build tries to run my eas-build-pre-install script during the build process. I have a script set up to install pnpm specifically for Android builds. The script content in scripts/eas-pre-install is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$EAS_BUILD_PLATFORM" == "android" ]]; then
  npm install -g pnpm@8.6.5
  pnpm --version
fi
```

In my package.json, I have defined the eas-build-pre-install script as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "eas-build-pre-install": "./scripts/eas-pre-install"
}

#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$EAS_BUILD_PLATFORM" == "android" ]]; then
  npm install -g pnpm@8.6.5
  pnpm --version
fi

Script 'eas-build-pre-install' is present in package.json, running it...

> app@0.0.1 eas-build-pre-install /home/expo/workingdir/build

> ./scripts/eas-pre-install

sh: 1: ./scripts/eas-pre-install: Permission denied

ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 126.

WARN   Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

pnpm run eas-build-pre-install exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the script pre-install has the execute permission. You can use the following command to grant execute permission:

```
chmod +x pre-install
```

After running this command, try executing your script again.